# Перестать дублировать зависимости библиотеки в проекте

Tags: android, gradle, библиотеки, android-gradle

Написал библиотеку, в которой есть следующие зависимости:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.12.2'
```

В своём проекте решил добавить эту библиотеку:

```
implementation 'com.mandarine.sdk:mandarine-library:2.0.1@aar'
```

Но так как в своём проекте я использовал те же зависимости что и в библиотеке, я решил их убрать с главного проекта и ссылаться только на те, которые есть в библиотеке, изменив в библиотеке `implementation` на `api`.
Пересобрал библиотеку, обновил зависимость в проекте на данную библиотеку, но увы проект не может использовать зависимости в этой библиотеке.

Получаю что то подобное:
https://gist.github.com/mnewlive/e0269a1f1b2a5062c6c16beb8329d268

Чистить проект, пересобирать, это всё пробовал. Не понимаю в чём загвоздка, ведь по сути так работать должно, потому как если я добавляю свою библиотеку через модуль и прописываю в `build.grade` проекта следующее:

```
implementation project(path: ':mandarine-library')
```

То всё работает.

Comment: Попробуйте добавить `{
            transitive = true
        }` после `implementation/api библиотека`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб да! и ещё раз да) пошло поехало)
А что конкретно он делает, если в двух словах)

Comment: Ну... Я точно не знаю, что оно делает, но, вроде, указывает, что можно использовать зависимости самой библиотеки)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб да, именно так) тоже в параллель прочёл) мол позволяет загружать и связывать их!
Оформите ответ к вопросу?) 
так как данное решение решает мою проблему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно добавить `{ transitive = true }` после `implementation/api ('ТУТ_БИБЛИОТЕКА')`.

Получится, например, так:

```
implementation ('com.saltedge.sdk:saltedge-library:2.0.2@aar') { transitive = true }
```

Таким способом указывается, что можно использовать зависимости самой библиотеки.

Comment: `implementation ('com.saltedge.sdk:saltedge-library:2.0.2@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }`
Скобочки потеряли :)

Comment: @Morozov, обновил ответ)